# Using GPT-2 with your own dictionary of words

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gpt-2

I'm training the gpt-2 with custom encodings and custom vocab.bpe file. However, when I generate text using gpt-2, the output tokens have range that exceeds the range of my new encodings. 
How can I make gpt-2 work for me then?

Comment: Could you please tell us how you solved it? I am trying to make a new `encoder.json` and `vocab.bpe` file for another language too and I couldn't find anything useful yet. Thank you.